# Dart: iterate through lists in lists

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list where it has values of another lists like this.

```
List[

    List[

        List[]
        ]
   ]
```

I want to iterate through lists in lists until the last list is null.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a recursive function like this:

```
_loopRecursively(List<int> _list){
 for(int i=0;i<_list[i];i++){
   if(_list[i] is List<int>){
     _loopRecuresively(_list[i]);
   }
 }
}
```

For recursive function references:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/